Div keeps on changing position with another div
I am trying to put the eye SVGs on my head. I have two separate SVGs which I put into two separate divs. Despite this, the black and white head guide which I temporarily implemented in my code to show where the eyes should be won't stay still and keeps moving with my other div. Here is my code:
.character {
   /* position: relative;*/

}

.part {
    position: absolute;
}

.head {
    /*animation: float 2s ease-in-out infinite;*/
    /*position: relative;*/
    margin-top:30px;
}
.headcolor {
   z-index: 1;
   margin-top: -500px;
   position: relative; 
}
/*soon, i will have to temporarily disable the floating animation to position the eyes, mouth, and whatever*/

.headoutline {
   z-index: 2;
   position: relative; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
}
/*
@keyframes float {
    0%, 100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(-5px); 
    }
}*/

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Character Assembly</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="player.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="guide">
        <object data="/svgs/char/shapes/30.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part body"></object>

    </div>
    
    <div class="character">
        <!-- Outline SVG -->
         
        <div class="head">
            <svg id="whole_head">
                <image href="/svgs/head/shapes/495.svg" id="headoutline"/>
    <svg id="head_shape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="90">



              <g transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 75.0, 45.0)">
    <path id="head_color" d="M75.0 0.0 Q75.0 18.65 53.0 31.8 31.05 45.0 0.0 45.0 -31.05 45.0 -53.05 31.8 -75.0 18.65 -75.0 0.0 -75.0 -18.65 -53.05 -31.85 -31.05 -45.0 0.0 -45.0 31.05 -45.0 53.0 -31.85 75.0 -18.65 75.0 0.0" fill="#ffcc66" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" />
  </g>

            <image href="/svgs/head/shapes/9.svg" id="headoutline"/>

  </svg>
</svg>




</div>
      <!--  <object data="body.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part body"></object>
        <object data="leftarms.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part arms"></object>
        <object data="rightarms.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part arms"></object>
        <object data="leftlegs.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part legs"></object>
        <object data="rightlegs.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part legs"></object>-->
    </div> 

    <script src="player.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Here is something which happens when I open inspect element and then change the margin-top of the head div:




.character {
   /* position: relative;*/

}

.part {
    position: absolute;
}

.head {
    /*animation: float 2s ease-in-out infinite;*/
    /*position: relative;*/
    margin-top:100px; 
    /*i tried to change this but the head in the guide div just came with it. the guide is supposed to stay where it is and not go with the colored head*/
}
.headcolor {
   z-index: 1;
   margin-top: -500px;
   position: relative; 
}
/*soon, i will have to temporarily disable the floating animation to position the eyes, mouth, and whatever*/

.headoutline {
   z-index: 2;
   position: relative;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
}
/*
@keyframes float {
    0%, 100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(-5px); 
    }
}*/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Character Assembly</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="player.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="guide">
        <object data="https://svgshare.com/i/1AxB.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part body"></object>

    </div>
    
    <div class="character">
        <!-- Outline SVG -->
         
        <div class="head">
            <svg id="whole_head">
                <image href="/svgs/head/shapes/495.svg" id="headoutline"/>
    <svg id="head_shape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="90">



              <g transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 75.0, 45.0)">
    <path id="head_color" d="M75.0 0.0 Q75.0 18.65 53.0 31.8 31.05 45.0 0.0 45.0 -31.05 45.0 -53.05 31.8 -75.0 18.65 -75.0 0.0 -75.0 -18.65 -53.05 -31.85 -31.05 -45.0 0.0 -45.0 31.05 -45.0 53.0 -31.85 75.0 -18.65 75.0 0.0" fill="#ffcc66" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" />
  </g>

<g transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 75.0, 45.0)">
    <path d="M53.0 -31.85 Q75.0 -18.65 75.0 0.0 75.0 18.65 53.0 31.8 31.05 45.0 0.0 45.0 -31.05 45.0 -53.05 31.8 -75.0 18.65 -75.0 0.0 -75.0 -18.65 -53.05 -31.85 -31.05 -45.0 0.0 -45.0 31.05 -45.0 53.0 -31.85 M51.05 -29.9 Q29.9 -42.25 0.0 -42.25 -29.9 -42.25 -51.05 -29.9 -72.2 -17.5 -72.2 0.0 -72.2 17.5 -51.05 29.85 -29.9 42.25 0.0 42.25 29.9 42.25 51.05 29.85 72.2 17.5 72.2 0.0 72.2 -17.5 51.05 -29.9" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0.49803922" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
  </g>

  </svg>
</svg>



</div>
      <!--  <object data="body.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part body"></object>
        <object data="leftarms.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part arms"></object>
        <object data="rightarms.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part arms"></object>
        <object data="leftlegs.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part legs"></object>
        <object data="rightlegs.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part legs"></object>-->
    </div> 

    <script src="player.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



with 100 px margin-top


.character {
   /* position: relative;*/

}

.part {
    position: absolute;
}

.head {
    /*animation: float 2s ease-in-out infinite;*/
    /*position: relative;*/
    margin-top:500px; 
    /*i tried to change this but the head in the guide div just came with it. the guide is supposed to stay where it is and not go with the colored head*/
}
.headcolor {
   z-index: 1;
   margin-top: -500px;
   position: relative; 
}
/*soon, i will have to temporarily disable the floating animation to position the eyes, mouth, and whatever*/

.headoutline {
   z-index: 2;
   position: relative;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
}
/*
@keyframes float {
    0%, 100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(-5px); 
    }
}*/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Character Assembly</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="player.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="guide">
        <object data="https://svgshare.com/i/1AxB.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part body"></object>

    </div>
    
    <div class="character">
        <!-- Outline SVG -->
         
        <div class="head">
            <svg id="whole_head">
                <image href="/svgs/head/shapes/495.svg" id="headoutline"/>
    <svg id="head_shape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="90">



              <g transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 75.0, 45.0)">
    <path id="head_color" d="M75.0 0.0 Q75.0 18.65 53.0 31.8 31.05 45.0 0.0 45.0 -31.05 45.0 -53.05 31.8 -75.0 18.65 -75.0 0.0 -75.0 -18.65 -53.05 -31.85 -31.05 -45.0 0.0 -45.0 31.05 -45.0 53.0 -31.85 75.0 -18.65 75.0 0.0" fill="#ffcc66" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" />
  </g>

<g transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 75.0, 45.0)">
    <path d="M53.0 -31.85 Q75.0 -18.65 75.0 0.0 75.0 18.65 53.0 31.8 31.05 45.0 0.0 45.0 -31.05 45.0 -53.05 31.8 -75.0 18.65 -75.0 0.0 -75.0 -18.65 -53.05 -31.85 -31.05 -45.0 0.0 -45.0 31.05 -45.0 53.0 -31.85 M51.05 -29.9 Q29.9 -42.25 0.0 -42.25 -29.9 -42.25 -51.05 -29.9 -72.2 -17.5 -72.2 0.0 -72.2 17.5 -51.05 29.85 -29.9 42.25 0.0 42.25 29.9 42.25 51.05 29.85 72.2 17.5 72.2 0.0 72.2 -17.5 51.05 -29.9" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0.49803922" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
  </g>

  </svg>
</svg>



</div>
      <!--  <object data="body.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part body"></object>
        <object data="leftarms.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part arms"></object>
        <object data="rightarms.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part arms"></object>
        <object data="leftlegs.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part legs"></object>
        <object data="rightlegs.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part legs"></object>-->
    </div> 

    <script src="player.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



with 500px margin top

Please make your code into a runnable snippet which shows the problem. We'll need to see the SVGs and also the code you have shown so far has a problem ( position: relative; margin in .headoutline settings in the CSS) which you need to correct.
